# Groups and U27 double check

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

This is just a quick question.

The Group U$_{27}$=$(1,2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23)$ right? Or am I just very wrong here?

Comment: Well, $2 \cdot 5 = 10$ is missing, while $(3,27) = 3 \neq 1$, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If by the group $U_{27}$ you mean the group of multiplicative units $\mod{27}$, you want the positive integers less than or equal to $27$ and less than $27$.  So $U_{27}=\{1,2,4,5,7,8,10,11,13,14,16,17,19,20,22,23,25,26\}$